# Prevent cells from updating in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

the problem is the following, I want cell to update to current HH:MM:SS and change the interior color, as soon as I change the value in another control cell.

The code I have compiled for that purpose is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

lRow = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("F3:F" & lRow)                       
For Each Cell In MR
            If (Cell.Value = "T") And (Time < Cells(Cell.Row, "E")) Then                        Cells(Cell.Row, "G").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    Cells(Cell.Row, "G").Value = Time
Next Cell

End Sub
```

However, what I get is the cells updating every time there is an action on the sheet while I want just a timestamp

Comment: What is the address of the control cell and what is the address of the timestamp cell??

Comment: Control cells are in the F range. MR range in the code. There is no timestamp cell. I take the time from the Time function.

Answer (score 0):

Change the event from `Worksheet_SelectiontChange` to `Worksheet_Change`. `Worksheet_SelectiontChange` is used to detect when a new/different range/cell is selected. Also, to limit to the change of a specific cell, just test the row and/or column of the provided `Target`. I'll often use a `Select Case` when I'm testing for multiple cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const COL_E = 5
    Const COL_F = 6
    Const COL_G = 7

    If Target.Column = COL_F Then

        Dim lRow As Long
        lRow = Target.Row

        If Cells(lRow, COL_F).Value = "T" Then
            Cells(lRow, COL_E).Value = Time
            Cells(lRow, COL_G).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Else
            ' clear the data?
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Just an FYI, OP stated in the comments that control cells are in the "F" range, which has a Column index of 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Given the restrictions on the Row (i.e = 2) works fine. However, I wish to use this functionality for all rows of column F. If I do that, and apply a T at a random row then the script will automatically populate all intermediate rows with the current time.

Comment: Wait, am I understanding that you want to update only the corresponding cell in the same row? E.g., if they update F3 you want to only update G3? Is that right?

Comment: I would have to be that for every T in F column you get a green color along with the timestamp in column G. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Ok, I updated the code sample. If this isn't exactly what you need, hopefully it is close enough to show you how to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that VBA is completely unnecessary in your use case.

Here's my suggestion: Unlock every editable cell in the Workbook, except for the control cell, add formula-based conditional formatting to your timestamp cell and protect the worksheet.

Much faster and easier to maintain.

Comment: That is true, however, I need to do it in VBA

Comment: @ArtTex can you say why this has to be in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Moved your Sub into the worksheet_change, reorganized the code (the Row.Count auto-find shouldn't be activated unless you are in the cells you want to be) And placed your variables in a stored condition array for easier updating.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim SC : SC = Split("3/6/T/E/G/10/F3:F/F", "/") 'Stored Conditions
    If Target.Row = Cint(SC(0)) and Target.Column = Cint(SC(1)) Then
        For Each Cell In Range(SC(6) & Range(SC(7) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
           If Cell.Value = SC(2) And Time < Cells(Cell.Row, SC(3)) Then 
                Cells(Cell.Row, SC(4)).Interior.ColorIndex = Cint(SC(5)) : Cells(Cell.Row, SC(4)).Value = Time
           End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```